# Pandas loc alternatives with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm planning improve readability for non Pandas developers; 
I have the following **working** Python code using `.loc`:

```
new_value = 'stackoverflow'
s_query = 'nbc'
SUGGESTED = 'suggested'
QUERY = 'query'
df.loc[(df[QUERY] == s_query), [SUGGESTED]] = new_value
```

Also have an option to:

```
new_value = 'stackoverflow'
s_query = 'nbc'
SUGGESTED = 'suggested'
QUERY = 'query'
df[SUGGESTED] = df[SUGGESTED].mask(df[QUERY] == s_query, new_value)
```

In this case `df[SUGGESTED]` column will be updated with `'stackoverflow'` value for the row(s) matching `df[QUERY] == s_query`.
Wondering if there is other options in Pandas to achieve same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.mask`s sister method `pd.DataFrame.where`, it makes the `False`s `nan` and fills in with the second argument

```
df[SUGGESTED] = df[SUGGESTED].where(df[QUERY] != s_query, new_value)
```

Or

```
df.update(df[QUERY].eq(s_query).map({True: new_value}))
```

Comment: Is there a way to not modify the False values and just change the row which matches the condition with new_value?

Comment: what I mean is that df[SUGGESTED] = np.where(df[QUERY] == s_query, new_value, np.nan) will update other rows with NaN, but Im just interested in updating one row.