# Pandas: Edit part of dataframe, have it affect main dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, filter

**EDIT:** A suggested possible duplicate ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196084/pandas-loc-alternatives-with-conditions)) is not a duplicate.  I'm asking if a slice of a dataframe can be edited and have that slice affect the original dataframe.  The "duplicate" Q/A suggested is just looking for an alternate to `.loc`.  The simple answer to my original question appears to be, "no".

**Original Question:**

This question likely has a duplicate somewhere, but I couldn't find it.  Also, I'm guessing what I'm about to ask isn't possible, but worth a shot.

I'm looking to be able to filter or mask a large dataframe, get a smaller dataframe for ease of coding, edit the smaller dataframe, and have it affect the larger dataframe.

So something like this:

```
df_full = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

df_part = df_full[df_full['a'] == 2]

df_part['b'] = 'Kentucky Fried Chicken'

print df_full
```

Would result in:

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  Kentucky Fried Chicken
2  3  6
```

I'm well aware of the ability to use the `.loc[row_indexer, col_indexer]` functionality, but even with a `mask` variable as the `row_indexer`, it can be a little unwieldy for more complex purposes.

A little context - I'm loading large database tables into a dataframe and want to make many edits on a small slice of it.  So the `.loc[]` gets tedious.  Maybe I could filter out that small slice, edit it, then re-append to the original?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas loc alternatives with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196084/pandas-loc-alternatives-with-conditions)

Comment: @Gregory - thanks for pointing that one out.  Didn't see it.  That said, per my edit, I don't think it's the same thing as I'm asking.

Comment: Also found this one, but no good answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972778/how-to-create-a-view-of-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: @Gregory - That second one _is_ a duplicate... or I should say my question is a duplicate of that one.  I would agree the OP for that question is asking the same thing as I am.  Looks like the answer is no different!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

No. You don't want to play the game where you have to keep checking / guessing whether you are using a copy or a view of a dataframe.

**Single update: the right way**

`.loc` accessor is the way to go. There is *nothing* unwieldy about it, though it takes some getting used to.

*However complex your criteria*, if it boils down to Boolean arrays, `.loc` accessor is *still* often the right choice. You need to show an example where it is genuinely difficult to implement.

```
df_full = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

df_full.loc[df_full['a'] == 2, 'b'] = 'Kentucky Fried Chicken'

#    a                       b
# 0  1                       4
# 1  2  Kentucky Fried Chicken
# 2  3                       6
```

**Single update: an alternative way**

If you find `.loc` accessor difficult to implement, one alternative is `numpy.where`:

```
df_full['b'] = np.where(df_full['a'] == 2, 'Kentucky Fried Chicken', df_full['b'])
```

**Multiple updates: for many conditions**

[`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) or [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) can be used to good effect to streamline your code. The usefulness of these will depend on the specific logic you are attempting to apply. The below question includes examples for each of these:

[Numpy “where” with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I was wondering if / hoping there was a way outside of the `.loc` accessor.

Comment: @pshep123, sure there is. I added an example. But, really, you should show an example where you believe it is "unwieldy"..